# Docker compose with wordpress:cli-php7.4 stalls on 'The site you have requested is not installed'?

Tags: docker

I have the following docker-compose.yml file where i'm using the [wordpress:cli-php7.4](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/tree/c0d11ed412fef07e748a5463041b7be0b5755dd6/php7.4/cli) to get the core wordpress and wp-cli image.

```
version: '3'
services:
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:cli-php7.4
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    volumes:
      - /home/dc-user/github/wordpress:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    networks:
      - back
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - back
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8001:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
    networks:
      - back
networks:
  back:
volumes:
  db_data:
```

I start the containers with this command

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Using portainer i see that three containers are created as expected and appear to be running. When I check the logs of the wordpress container i see this error

```
Error: The site you have requested is not installed.
Run `wp core install` to create database tables.
```

Attempting to open a CLI to the container says that it's still restarting. Is there some extra command or information i need to provide?

Comment: Those docker images are not maintained or provided by WordPress, but rather they are created by the creators of Docker themselves. Nobody from the WordPress project is involved in them. If you need help with those containers, you need to speak with the maintainers of those containers. They're only official in the sense that they are provided by docker themselves